# Pantech Tablet Simulator

Tags: android, simulator

Please help me to find simulator for pantech tablets which is running on Android OS. I need to solve one issue coming in the webpage when I tested that page in default browser of the pantech tablet device. Currently I am not having the actual pantech tablet. Please help me in this.

Comment: There's a generic but customisable android emulator available with the android sdk - see http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html - but you're unlikely to find a simulator for that specific hardware.

Comment: Thanks AndrewC. I solved the defect. The defect is because of the inclusion of the string "Webkit" in the User Agent in the ICS version of pantech tablet.In honeyComb "Webkit" is not there in the user agent string. We have done some scripting, targeting desktop webkit browsers using"Webkit" keyword in user agent string  which affects the ICS version as it contains the "Webkit" keyword in user agent string.

Comment: Well done. Why not add that as your own answer and mark it as accepted using the tick?

Comment: Thanks Again For ur suggestion AndrewC I did that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the defect which is coming only in the Android ICS Pantech tablets. Issue is not reproducible on other previous versions.

The actual issue is because of the inclusion of the string "Webkit" in the User Agent in the ICS version of pantech tablet.In honeyComb "Webkit" is not there in the user agent string. We have done some scripting, targeting desktop webkit browsers using"Webkit" keyword in user agent string which affects the ICS version as it contains the "Webkit" keyword in user agent string.